# C++: Error in login, identify a valid triangle with greater greater then 0, all three angles provided

Tags: c++, triangle

I have written this program, it passes all manual test conditions but says "wrong answer" when I submit online on an IDE.
Constraints
0≤a,b,c≤180

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    double a,b,c;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    if(a+b+c==180)
    cout<<"YES";
    else
    cout<<"NO";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked edge cases like `0,0,180`, and we can't use `==` to compare double values for a precision reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken.

Comment: Q: Does the program work for you when you build and execute it yourself.  Q: Have you considered the fact that "==" is *NOT* a good idea with floating point arithmetic.  MOST IMPORTANT: `[it] says "wrong answer" when I submit online on an IDE...`.  What the heck does that mean?  WHAT "on line IDE"???  Does this IDE give you any clue what it doesn't like?  Please clarify...

Comment: Input of `-50 230 0` will incorrectly pass your test.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin thanks for the hints I made changes to the logic and it worked.

Comment: @Peter you were I added the condition that a,b,c >0 and it's working absolutely fine now

Answer (score -1):

The above code doesn't give correct answer  when either of a,bc is zero and the a+b+c=180.
So,

```
int main()
{
// your code goes here
double a,b,c;
cin>>a>>b>>c;
//add the below statement
if((a!=0)&&(b!=0)&&(c!=0)){
if(a+b+c==180)
cout<<"YES";
else
cout<<"NO";
}
else{
 cout<<"NO";
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
// your code goes here
double a,b,c;
cin>>a>>b>>c;
//made the changes with the help of suggestion from the forum
if((a>0)&&(b>0)&&(c>0)&&(a+b+c==180))
cout<<"YES";
else
cout<<"NO";


return 0;
}
```